# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que me envíe el codigo a un celular real?

Tags: android, firebase

Realmente solo logro que me logge pero con el de prueba de Firebase.
Esta es la parte del código donde la función debería enviarlo

```
    private void VerifNum(String s){
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(s,60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, this,mCallbacks);
    }

    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks= new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                super.onCodeSent(verificationId,forceResendingToken);
                mVerificationId=verificationId;
                token=forceResendingToken;
                Toast.makeText(NumbAuthe.this, "ENVIADO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
            String code=phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
            if(code!=null){
                Toast.makeText(NumbAuthe.this, "COMPLETADO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                VerifCode(code);
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
            Toast.makeText(NumbAuthe.this, "ERROR ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recordá que el teléfono debe tener el código de area antes del numero, por ejemplo en Argentina un número válido para mandar el mensaje sería

```
+54  tu_codigo_de_area_local + telefono
```

Ejemplo

```
+540351154321098
```

De esta forma te debería enviar el mensaje a tu dispositivo

Comment: Gracias, me corrigió el error. Se lo agradezco en verdad

Comment: Puedes marcar esta respuesta como correcta si te sirvió, un saludo @MenLeal

Comment: Y como puedo escribir en dos nodos a la ves? Usted sabe? Tengo esa duda

Comment: Puedes hacer otra pregunta con este detalle y lo puedo responder , asi tenemos mas contexto sobre lo que necesitas, un saludo

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/384972/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-escribir-dos-nodos-en-la-base-de-datos-de-firebase-al-mismo-tiempo

Comment: Aquí está el link, gracias en verdad